# Codec that converts amr-wb multichannel file to mpeg3 or .wav needed

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, amr

I've got Linux Ubuntu and ffmpeg version 4.3-2. It converts monochannel 16kHz 16kbit/s amr-wb files to wav without any problems, but when it comes to amr-wb **multichannel** files the output is:

```
filename.amr: Operation not permitted
```

I've already tried for test purposes to encode a [stereo.wav](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=audiotestfiles)  file into an amr-wb file, but without success. The ffmpeg codec converts it into a normal monofile with just one channel. Seems that the multichannel mode is unknown for it.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ffmpeg supports one amr-wb encoder: libvo_amrwbenc. This encoder only supports mono. Two amr-wb decoders are supported: amrwb & libopencore_amrwb. I didn't look into what they support and don't have a sample file to try, but consider trying both (such as `ffmpeg -c:a libopencore_amrwb -i input output`)

Comment: @llogan I'm only interested in the decoders. Does one of those support stereo (an amr-wb file in multichannelmode) ?  thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't have a sample file. You can give it a try or view the source code.